# Match regexp group

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions

I am trying to modify org-wikinodes.el to match any org-mode headline (not just camelCase text. So I have replaced the default regular expression with:

```
*\\s-\\(.+\\)
```

This works. But in order to link back to say `My headline` I have to write my link as `* My headline`.

The question is, how can I get org-mode to only match group 1 of the regex, so that I can link back to `My headline` without including the `*`?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a look at [wikinodes.el](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/org-wikinodes.el;hb=HEAD). CamelCase is inherent to that mode. You cannot reach your objective through just changing the regular expression `org-wikinodes-camel-regexp`. See, e.g., `org-wikinodes-activate-links`.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the first match in code, i.e. the `(match-beginning 1)` function, or how to change the file so that it uses the first sub-match rather than the whole match (i.e. change 0 to 1), or how to write a better regular expression to match an org-mode headline, or does elisp have lookbehind in regular expressions (no) or something else? I agree with @Tobias if my guesses of what you want to do are correct.

Comment: I would like to write a regex that matches the first group only: thus returning the heading minus the "* ". Thanks.